# Not able to print PHP JSON array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am trying to print JSON array returned by PHP to print in jQuery but with no luck.

**PHP Code**

```
$json = array();
$res = "";
foreach($cor as $service){
     $res .= "Some Divs.... long HTML response here";
}
$json['responses'] = $res;
$this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$(document).delegate('#button', 'click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:  $("#form").serialize(),
        beforeSend: function() {
                $this.button('loading');
        },
        complete: function() {
                $this.button('reset');
        },
        success: function(json) {
                $("#resp").html(json['responses']);
                console.log(json['responses']);
        },
        error: function(data, status, error ) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

In above, i get output in console `console.log(json['responses']);`. I can see proper HTML rendered in console.

But Div with `$("#resp").html(json['responses']);` does not have anything to show. :(

`#resp`, Yes it exists on the page.

Isn't it weird and frustrating. :(

Network tab Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: is it valid html? jquery may not add it if it can't be parsed properly, or parse it wrong, causing it to be rendered wrong.

Comment: how would i know that????

Comment: you're the one building the html. you should know what you're building.

Comment: yes.. but invalid html can mean many things.. wat u like to point at?

Comment: If you look in the Elements tab of the console, do you see anything in the `#resp` DIV?

Comment: @Barmar ... Nop.. nothing is in that div

Comment: Maybe something else is removing it. Set a breakpoint after `$("#resp").html(json['responses'])` and check the DOM.

Comment: Morning is always fresh to work.... Vry bad thing i have done... my div says `<div id="post mt"></div>` .. i have given 2 IDs fr Div.. reeeaallyy Badddd thing... now all is well

Answer (score 0):

1- use "`echo json_encode($json);`" instead of this

> $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
>
> $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));

2- change following code

```
 success: function(json) {
    $("#resp").html(json.responses);
    console.log(json.responses);
  },
```

Comment: If you think there's a difference between `json["responses"]` and `json.responses`, you don't understand Javascript objects.